# How to Determine if a Character Is a Vowel

Tags: c++

I am trying to get use `vector[].substr()` but i don't know if this is possible. Does anyone know another way to do this?  My goal is to take a word that is in vector and separate it from the first vowel. any help is appreciated. my code looks like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "derrick_math.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string phrase;
    string ay = "ay";
    vector<string> vec;
    cout << "Please enter the word or phrase to translate: ";
    getline(cin, phrase);

    istringstream iss(phrase);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), 
         istream_iterator<string>(), 
         back_inserter(vec));
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vec[i].substr(0, 1) == "a || e || i || o || u || A || E || I || O || U")
    {
        cout << vec[i] << "ay";
    }
    if (vec[i].substr(1, 1) == "a || e || i || o || u || A || E || I || O || U")
    {
        cout << vec[i].substr(2) << vec[i].substr(0, 1) << "ay";
    }
    if (vec[i].substr(2, 1) == "a || e || i || o || u || A || E || I || O || U")
    {
        cout << vec[i].substr(3), vec[i].substr(0, 2) + "ay";
    }
    if (vec[i].substr(3, 1) == "a || e || i || o || u || A || E || I || O || U")
    {
        cout << vec[i].substr(4), vec[i].substr(0, 3) + ay;
    }
    cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: For your own sake, write something like `bool isVowel(char)`. That will help you __tremendously__.

Comment: What would you expect `vec[].substr()` to do if `vec` was an `std::vector<int>`?

Answer (score 5):

Accessing the member functions of your vector's elements is not your problem. Your if statements are malformed. Currently you are comparing the substring against one long string, and that will never evaluate to true in this case.

If you want to check for a specific character you will need something like this:

```
bool is_vowel(char c) {
    c = tolower(c);
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}
```

Or...

```
bool is_vowel(char c) {
    switch(tolower(c)) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can call your function like so:

```
std::string s = vec[i];
if(is_vowel(s[n])) {
    // the third character is a vowel
}
```

There are some other issues with your code as well.  This line:

```
cout << vec[i].substr(4), vec[i].substr(0, 3) + ay;
```

Should probably be:

```
// no comma operator
cout << vec[i].substr(4) << vec[i].substr(0, 3) + ay;
```

To add an item to the end of your vector, all you need is:

```
vec.push_back(s);
```

Comment: [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) would make things even easier: `s.find_first_of("AEIOUaeiou")`.

Comment: @Zeta: Sure, but I wanted to show what was wrong with his if statement.

Comment: And I would have done the same thing, see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480478/how-to-determine-if-a-character-is-a-vowel/27480768?noredirect=1#comment43394116_27480478). Nevertheless OP still wants to find the first vowel, and your example uses `if(is_vowel(s[n]))` (I think you meant `s[2]` btw). So why stop there? That's a perfect opportunity to introduce `for` or `std::find` or reference `find_first_of`.

Comment: @Zeta: I meant `s[n]`.  He checks for multiple indices; I was just showing that indexing into a string returns a `char`.  I could add further ways to solve the problem, but honestly, for someone who doesn't yet have the syntax down, I'm not convinced that going into further detail is very helpful. It certainly can't hurt, but he has a ways to go still.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [std::string::find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/)

This will find the position of the first match for any character founded in the argument.
Then just separate it with substr like

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
    size_t pos = vec[i].find_first_of("aAeEiIoOuU");
    std::string result = "";

    if (pos != std::string::npos){ // Check if find_first_of got a match
        result = vec[i].substr(pos + 1);
    }
    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT** if you instead was trying to get the vocal you could use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
    size_t pos = vec[i].find_first_of("aAeEiIoOuU");
    char result;

    if (pos != std::string::npos){
        result = vec[i][pos];
    }
    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;
}
```