# How to calculate vowels next to each other in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a problem with one of my homeworks. My task is the following:

- write a program in C++
- input: a string
- output: numbers of vowels next to each other
- example: input -> computers; output -> 1 2 1 2 (because c,mp,t,rs)

I have already tried a couple of things but it isn't working.
This is one of my attempts:

```
cout << "Type your word: ";
cin >> YourWord;
cout << "Your word is: " << YourWord << endl;

//maganhangzók
char a = 'a';
char e = 'e';
char i = 'i';
char o = 'o';
char u = 'u';

//massalhangzok
char b = 'b';
char c = 'c';
char d = 'd';
char f = 'f';
char g = 'g';
char h = 'h';
char j = 'j';
char k = 'k';
char l = 'l';
char m = 'm';
char n = 'n';
char p = 'p';
char q = 'q';
char r = 'r';
char s = 's';
char t = 't';
char v = 'v';
char w = 'w';
char x = 'x';
char y = 'y';
char z = 'z';

int counter[YourWord.length()];
int nothing = 0;

for(int i=1; i<YourWord.length(); i++) {
    if (((YourWord[i] = a) || (YourWord[i] = e) || (YourWord[i] =  i) || (YourWord[i] = o) || (YourWord[i] = u)) && ((YourWord[i-1] = a) || (YourWord[i-1] = e) || (YourWord[i-1] =  i) || (YourWord[i-1] = o) || (YourWord[i-1] = u))) {
        nothing++;
    } else if (((YourWord[i] = a) || (YourWord[i] = e) || (YourWord[i] =  i) || (YourWord[i] = o) || (YourWord[i] = u)) && ((YourWord[i-1] = b) || (YourWord[i-1] = c) || (YourWord[i-1] = d) || (YourWord[i-1] = f) || (YourWord[i-1] = g) || (YourWord[i-1] = j) || (YourWord[i-1] = k) || (YourWord[i-1] = l) || (YourWord[i-1] = m) || (YourWord[i-1] = n) || (YourWord[i-1] = p) || (YourWord[i-1] =  q) || (YourWord[i-1] = r) || (YourWord[i-1] = s) || (YourWord[i-1] = t) || (YourWord[i-1] =  v) || (YourWord[i-1] =  w) || (YourWord[i-1] = x) || (YourWord[i-1] = y) || (YourWord[i-1] = z))) {
        counter[i] = counter[i];
    } else if (((YourWord[i] = b) || (YourWord[i] = c) || (YourWord[i] =  d) || (YourWord[i] = f) || (YourWord[i] = g) || (YourWord[i] = j) || (YourWord[i] =  k) || (YourWord[i] = l) || (YourWord[i] = m) || (YourWord[i] = n) || (YourWord[i] = p) || (YourWord[i] = q) || (YourWord[i] = r) || (YourWord[i] = s) || (YourWord[i] = t) || (YourWord[i] = v) || (YourWord[i] =  w) || (YourWord[i] = x) || (YourWord[i] = y) || (YourWord[i] = z)) && ((YourWord[i-1] = b) || (YourWord[i-1] = c) || (YourWord[i-1] =  d) || (YourWord[i-1] = f) || (YourWord[i-1] = g) || (YourWord[i-1] = j) || (YourWord[i-1] = k) || (YourWord[i-1] = l) || (YourWord[i-1] = m) || (YourWord[i-1] = n) || (YourWord[i-1] = p) || (YourWord[i-1] = q) || (YourWord[i-1] = r) || (YourWord[i-1] = s) || (YourWord[i-1] = t) || (YourWord[i-1] =  v) || (YourWord[i-1] =  w) || (YourWord[i-1] = x) || (YourWord[i-1] = y) || (YourWord[i-1] = z))) {
        counter[i]++;
    } else {
            counter[i+1]++;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is unnecessarily complicated and absolutely unusable.
Could anyone help me with a hint where should I start?

Comment: What about `y`? Isn't that a vowel? Guessing it's not a vowel in hungarian.

Comment: Handy reading: [How to Determine if a Character Is a Vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480478/how-to-determine-if-a-character-is-a-vowel)

Comment: `YourWord[i] = a` assigns the value of `a` to `YourWord[i]`. `YourWord[i] == a` compares the two values.

Comment: In your question, you speak of outputting the "number of vowels next to each other". However, it seems you mean the number of "consonants", not "vowels".

Comment: You can use a string variable `listOfGoodChars` containing all vowels (or all consonants as hinted by Andreas above). A list of all vowels is __data__ not code ! Then use form 4 of the `find` string method as described here:[find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) ; like `pos = listOfGoodChars.find(ch); if (pos != std::npos) { YES it's a good character ...`

Comment: You have overcomplicated the solution. You just need to loop through the characters in the word, keeping a count of the number of non-vowels. For every vowel you encounter you output the count and reset it. Finally output the count.

Comment: Peter Becker and Andreas Wanzel both of you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A problem with your code is that it seems to be trying to do two things at once:

1. decide whether a character lies in the *chosen set* or not
2. based on these decisions, compute the requested numbers.

In the interest of readability, part 2 should *use* part 1, not include it.

This is even more so as you seem to use very long code lines. So the reader has to use the horizontal slider, in which case it is not possible to simultaneously see both the end of a long code line and the shorter code lines that follow. This makes it more difficult to find the bugs.

This being C++ hence object-oriented programming, we can delegate the decision of whether a character is part of the chosen ones to some ad hoc object, of say a *CharTester* class. The `CharTester` object receives at creation time a string containing all "chosen" characters. This way, the algorithm that computes the requested numbers can be much shorter.

The CharTester object can delegate all the hard work to the string [find method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

The source code to create this auxiliary object would go for example like this:

```
    static const char  EnglishConsonantList[] =
        "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";
    CharTester  cht(EnglishConsonantList);
```

A nice thing with the above coding style is that, if some official Grammatical Committee decides that from now on, Y will be a consonant instead of a vowel, the required changes in your source code are minimal. And your teacher is possibly not above saying such as « *Now that you've done it for consonants, please do it for vowels.* » - this in order to force you to realize how flexible your source code exactly is.

Thus we are lead to the following code, where the most interesting piece is the `goodCharCounts()` function, which returns an `std::vector` object containing the requested numbers.

```
#include  <vector>
#include  <string>
#include  <iostream>

using  std::string;
using  std::cout;


class CharTester {
public:
    CharTester(const string& list) : goodCharList(list)
    {};
    bool isGoodChar(char ch) const;

private:
    string  goodCharList;    // list of "chosen" characters
};

bool CharTester::isGoodChar(char ch) const
{
    // hard work there:
    bool isGood = (goodCharList.find(ch) != string::npos);

    return isGood;
}


// THE ALGORITHM:

std::vector<int>  goodCharCounts(const CharTester& cht, const std::string& str)
{
    std::vector<int>  posVec;

    int  counter = 0;
    // loop on all characters of the input string
    for (char ch : str) {
        bool isGood = cht.isGoodChar(ch);

        if (isGood) {
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter > 0) {
            // end of current "chosen" group, so must register it
            posVec.push_back(counter);
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    if (counter > 0) {
        // register last "chosen" group
        posVec.push_back(counter);
        counter = 0;
    }

    return  posVec;
}
```

We can test the algorithm by adding the following main program:

```
// test one string and print the results:
void doUnitTest(const CharTester& cht, const string& str)
{
    std::vector<int>  counts = goodCharCounts(cht, str);

    cout << str << " --> ";
    // loop on all numbers:
    for (int n : counts) {
        cout << n << ' ';
    }
    cout << std::endl;
}


// possible lists of "chosen" characters :

//-- const wchar_t FrenchVowelList[]      = L"AEIOUYÀÂÉÊÈÏÔÛÙaeiouyàâéêèïôûù";
//-- const wchar_t RussianVowelList[]     = L"АЕИОЭЙЫЮЯЁУаеиоэйыюяёу";

static const char  EnglishVowelList[] =  "aeiouyAEIOUY";
static const char  EnglishConsonantList[] =
    "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";


int main()
{
    CharTester  cht(EnglishConsonantList);  

    doUnitTest(cht, "computers");
    doUnitTest(cht, "Some computers are cheap. Aeiuo-XrZT.");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Execution:

```
computers --> 1 2 1 2 
Some computers are cheap. Aeiuo-XrZT. --> 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 4
```

### Side note:

Above, I have used the `char` type and the associated classic C++ `string` type, because this is how you proceed in your code. However, for production code, you would probably have to use the more general *wide* `wchar_t` and `wstring` types, in order to allow for non-ASCII characters such as á, à, ê, ẞ., etc... (Unicode characters).